# Logic between options and risk free rate

Tags: options, put-call-parity, risk-free

What is the relationship between put option price and risk free rate? And between call options price and risk free rate? Explain the logic? No calculation.

Comment: [Cross-posted to economics](http://economics.stackexchange.com/q/8686/5733), please note [cross-posting is not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/266114).

Comment: As a general rule, in a high interest rate environment it is advantageous to postpone payments and disadvantageous to postpone receipts. Therefore a call option (option to buy and pay later) increases in value when interest rates rise, while a put option (option to sell and receive payment later) decreases in value as interest rates rise.

Comment: As you can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_%28finance%29#Formulas_for_European_option_Greeks the RHO of a European call is positive, while the RHO of a European put is negative.